# What does this specific script tag do? What is the app:// protocol?

Tags: javascript, html, .net-core, script-tag

I'm working with a new Open Source library / framework named [Photino](https://www.tryphotino.io/) (cross-platform desktop apps built with HTML5 frontend and .NET core).  Github repo is [here](https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.NET).

**HTML As User Interface**

When a Photino application starts, it loads an HTML page which becomes the desktop app's User Interface.

**Template Projects**

The Photino project provides template projects and the basic one (built with command `$ dotnet new photinoapp -o <projname>`) contains a index.html page that contains the following script tag:

```
<script src="app://dynamic.js"></script>
```

**What I've Tried**
From everything I can tell the project doesn't use this anywhere.

1. Searched through source code of entire project.
2. Read all Photino [documentation](https://docs.tryphotino.io/).
3. Searched web extensively

However, I cannot find any reference to :

1. the app:// protocol
2. dynamic.js
3. anything explaining what this might be

I'm assuming it can just be removed from the project, but I'm curious about what the project template creators might have intended.  Have you ever seen this before?  Do you know what it is used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app` is being used as a key to set up a [protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/protocol_handlers) to your application.

From that linked document:

> A protocol handler is an application that knows how to handle particular types of links: for example, a mail client is a protocol handler for "mailto:" links.

The [photino.NET](https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.Samples/blob/master/Photino.HelloPhotino.NET/Program.cs#L28) sample `program.cs` has below statement.

```
var window = new PhotinoWindow()
    .SetTitle(windowTitle)
    // More statements here left out for brevity
    .RegisterCustomSchemeHandler(
        "app", (object sender, string scheme, string url, out string contentType) =>
    {
        contentType = "text/javascript";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"
            (() =>{
                window.setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(` Dynamically inserted JavaScript.`);
                }, 1000);
            })();
        "));
    })
```

It is the `RegisterCustomSchemeHandler` that registers the protocol handler using that `app` key.
It  sets up a callback function that will be called when given `app` key gets found in a page that is being loaded.

The source code of [RegisterCustomSchemeHandler](https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.NET/blob/6d201c3b6d7345d6ad54f4af3c5beb37b5adf0ef/Photino.NET/PhotinoNetDelegates.cs#L191) mentions:

> Registers user-defined custom schemes (other than 'http', 'https' and 'file') and handler methods to receive callbacks when the native browser control encounters them.

The [index.html](https://github.com/tryphotino/photino.Samples/blob/master/Photino.HelloPhotino.NET/wwwroot/index.html) from that sample has below `script` tag.

```
<script src="app://dynamic.js"></script>
```

This triggers the callback, which returns the client side script that you want to get executed for given `script` tag.

For above example the `url` argument in `(object sender, string scheme, string url, out string contentType)` will contain `app://dynamic.js`.

The provided sample ignores the incoming value and just returns a constant/hard-coded script, but you might decide upon returning the content of a file that matches given url.

That part after `app://` in a `script` tag can be any `string` value of your choice that might be meaningful for your application.

Comment: Fantastic detailed answer.  Thanks very much.